# Show data with subitems data (TableView, ListView or ScrollView)

Tags: android, ios, uitableview, listview, appcelerator

In order to create an Alloy Calendar module for Titanium (Appcelerator), I've done some attempts and these were the fastest and better ones.

The thing is, the calendar starts with 30 default days (main items) if the user scrolls to the end, at some point, there are loaded more 7 days (main items), at some point, if the user stills push more results, lets say a total of 730 rows (2 years), thats a lot.

**Questions**

- There is any way to have subitems on a TableViewRow or ListItem (like ExpandableListView)?
- Witch one of this approaches do you think is the best?
- If you choose one of the following approaches, do you have any thing to add or change?

**1# - ScrollView**

With a horizontal layout, 30 inner ScrollViews every time that the users scrolls to the start or the end of the ScrollView, more 10 ScrollView are added/insertedAt to the ScrollView (depending on the scrollend position). This approach it's very poor in performance;

**2# - TableView** (rotated -90º)

With 30 TableViewRows (rotated -90), every time that the users scrolls to the start or the end of the TableView, the data is set again but now with the new 10 TableViewRows;

**3# - ListView** (rotated -90º) with ListView

This is a main ListView (alloy), each item has it's own ListView (common js) added in the controller when is created a new ListItem to the main ListView, this was the best version of my widget, but there are 2 issues on this: every time that the main ListView reaches the end or the beginning of the ListView, all the inner ListViews seems like that switch the content and it was almost impossible to get the selected element or data.

**4# - ListView** (rotated -90º)

The same as the above, but with inner TableViews, I could't select the clicked row, because the data was added as the data property of the TableView bindId, so in order to create an work around to this, I've tried to add a number of default rows to each item, but, at the time to build the app, it crashes when compiling, I was forced to change the TableView to an vertical ScrollView with 30 default inner items, and set an array of labels to each item the property children.

**Final Thoughts**

All of this approaches has it's own pros and cons, but the only 2 that worked without bugs, was the ones that didn't contain ListView. The ones with the ListView were the fastest.

The one that I've didn't try, it's an ScrollView or TableView with the inner data showed in a ListView, but I don't think that this will help performance.

**Result**

[image]